# Can't call firebase database function inside GoogleSignin signIn function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-signin

I'm using react-native-google-signin to achieve google login function. After setting up all the configuration steps, I'm able to get 'user' from GoogleSignin.signIn().then((user) => {...}.

Now I want to check whether this user has already used 'this' google account. Because if yes, I don't need to create the user data in the firebase database. But if not (first time), I need to create the user data inside the Google signin function. Here is my code.

```
import fire from '../../firebase'

.. ..

GoogleSignin.signIn()
  .then((user) => {
    console.log('get user');  // I can get user here

    // This firebase function can't be called (no reaction)
    fire.database().ref('Users').child(user.id).once('value', snapshot => {

      console.log('inside function');  // can't log it

      if(!snapshot.val()) {
        console.log('new');  // can't log it
        fire.database().ref('Users').child(user.id).child('User_Data').set({
          username: user.name,
          email: user.email,
          avatar: user.photo
        });
      }

      else {
        console.log('old');  // can't log it
        fire.database().ref('Users').child(user.id).child('User_Data').update({
          username: user.name,
          email: user.email,
          avatar: user.photo
        });
      }
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('WRONG SIGNIN', err);
  })
  .done();
```

I can only get the 'user' data. No new Google email is created in my Firebase Authentication screen. Also, no new user data is created in my database.

Does anyone have the same issue or the solution? Thanks for any help or idea!

Answer (score 0):

I don't use React so this might not help, but have you tried to re-factor your code to something like this;

```
function googleSignIn() {
  GoogleSignin.signIn()
    .then(validateSignIn) // Might need to be `this.validateSignIn`
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('WRONG SIGNIN', err);
    })
    .done();
}

function validateSignIn(user) {
  console.log('get user');  // I can get user here

  // This firebase function can't be called (no reaction)
  fire.database().ref('Users').child(user.id).once('value', snapshot => {

    console.log('inside function');  // can't log it

    if(!snapshot.val()) {
      console.log('new');  // can't log it
      fire.database().ref('Users').child(user.id).child('User_Data').set({
        username: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        avatar: user.photo
      });
    }

    else {
      console.log('old');  // can't log it
      fire.database().ref('Users').child(user.id).child('User_Data').update({
        username: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        avatar: user.photo
      });
    }
}
```

This way the `validateSignIn` function is in it's own function and not encapsulated by your thenable object.

Comment: Hello sketchthat, thanks for the help! But it doesn't work :(

Comment: Did you try calling both with `this` and without? (`this.validateSignIn` and `validateSignIn`)

Comment: Hello sketchthat, I solved this issue. The problem is I didn't use GoogleAuthProvider in the API. Now I'm able to sign in with Google. Thank you!